# Как сохранить массив изображений или коллекцию массива байтов одним файлом?

Tags: массивы, java

Как сохранить массив изображений или коллекцию массива байтов одним файлом, не используя базу данных типа `SQLite`?

```
Example: Bitmap[] or List<byte[]>
```

Comment: Другие базы данных тоже не подходят!

Comment: Мдя, загадка века!

Comment: Можно сохранить в Zip ну или Rar )))) Это уже дело вкуса.. а если серьезно то какова цель и оправдано ли сохронять массив матриц в один файл? я бы наверное если это не для мобилок то создал одну матрицу по размерам всех. скопировал туда все матрицы и сохронил в файл. как то так. но все зависит от задачи

Comment: SATALIN, Проблема, как раз в том, что это для мобилок, и условие мне такое вот поставили на фирме в тестовом задании на  работу. Реализовал всё, и довольно быстро, а вот тут запоролся... Один файлом, и не базу данных... А по поводу матриц: никогда с ними ещё не работал.

Comment: А чем вам обычная сериализация не угодила?

Comment: VladD, не работает она с этим

Comment: @FRIST_008: даже с массивом байт? [Не может быть.](http://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) или [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html). 
Думаю, для вашей задачи это подойдет.

ЕМНИП ObjectOutputStream записывает только сериализуемые объекты.

И еще: что мешает расширить DataOutputStream чтобы записывать (а в дальшейшем через InputStream читать) коллекцию?

Быстренько написал код - http://pastebin.com/g6wHCnXD

Возможно, он поможет вам, а возможно я не так понял суть проблемы.

Comment: ObjectOutputStream не хочет работать с Bitmap или byte[].
ByteArrayOutputStream работает только с массивом байтов (byte[]), а не с коллекцией массивов байтов.

Comment: ЕМНИП ObjectOutputStream записывает только сериализуемые объекты. 
И еще: что мешает расширить DataOutputStream чтобы записывать (а в дальшейшем через InputStream читать) коллекцию? 
Быстренько написал код - http://pastebin.com/g6wHCnXD
Возможно, он поможет вам, а возможно я не так понял суть проблемы.

Comment: А записать всю коллекцию с помощью ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()?

Comment: rfq, а вы уверенны что все что расширяет List сериализуемо? По сути должно быть так (по крайней мере ArrayList точно подлежит записи через writeObject() - public class ArrayList<E> ... implements ... java.io.Serializable), но что автор сам не расширяет List не факт ;)

Comment: rfq, Пишет ошибку, мол для массива байтов надо использовать ByteArrayOutputStream. (Читайте выше мой комментарий)

Comment: Alex18, Оо, http://pastebin.com/g6wHCnXD работает!!!


****Протирая глаза и смотря на код****, пока не очень понимаю как, так как не работал с DataOutputStream, но оно работает!

Пошел разбираться с тем, что вы сделали. Это гениальное решение!

Жаль пока очков уважения не хватает, чтобы плюсануть ваш ответ... но как наберётся обязательно это сделаю!

Спасибо!=)

Comment: кто пишет? компилятор? ну так приведите к Object: ObjectOutputStream oos; oos.writeObject((Object)array).

Comment: rfq, делал, тоже самое...

Barmaley, Именно для этого не хватает.
Цитирую: Недостаточно очков уважения 
для выполнения действия голос за.
Минимальная требуемая репутация - 15 (у вас 11). Загляните в справку.

Comment: @FRIST_008 а нажать кнопку "Like" слева от ответа - тоже не хватает очков? Я, кстати, нажал - и вам советую...

Comment: @FRIST_008 ну не знаю, у меня byte[][] data=...;    oos.writeObject(data); сработало без ошибок. Если хотите, чтобы вам помогали, потрудитесь точнее приводить сообщения об ошибках, а не заявляйте голословно, что якобы "ObjectOutputStream не хочет работать с Bitmap или byte[]". И выложите исходный код на pastebin или куда-нибудь еще.